# How passing a container(list/dictionary) to a function would be different in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data structure/container-python list/dictionary that I want to update based some computation. There are a few ways I have in mind:

1.

```
new_list=list() # initialised globally!

def func():
  for i in range(5):
    new_list.append(i) # updtaing here!
  print('in function:', new_list)
  pass

def main():
  print('before:', new_list)
  func()
  print('after:',new_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

2.

```
def func(container):
  for i in range(5):
    container.append(i)
  print('in function:', container)
  pass

def main():
  new_list=list()
  print('before:', new_list)
  func(new_list)
  print('after:',new_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

3.

```
def func(container):
  for i in range(5):
    container.append(i)
  print('in function:', container)
  return container

def main():
  new_list=list()
  print('before:', new_list)
  new_list = func(new_list)
  print('after:',new_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Could anyone explain what the difference between the 3 versions.? Logically all 3 of them work and even the results are same! but I am curious to know what the difference between these approaches and which is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Globals are evil. For this specific example, it might work. But if you would later decide to add a second list, you would have to rewrite your code or duplicate your functions. And it would be more complicated to write unit tests for the function.
2. I think there's nothing wrong with this approach in general.
3. This might be a matter of taste. Returning the object has no real purpose here, since the caller already has the object. And returning it might give the impression that the returned object is a different object. So personally, I wouldn't recommend this approach. I think this pattern is more often used in some other high-level object oriented programming languages as Java (or possibly C++), but I don't think it's very Pythonic.

PS: The `pass` statements do not have any effect. Why did you add these?

---

**UPDATE:** Extending a bit on your related question about how arguments are passed (by value or reference) and how that impacts the code:

In Python, all types are classes, and are passed by reference. When you assign a value to a local variable (e.g. the function argument), a new reference is made, but the caller still refers to the original object. However, when you modify the contents of the object, the caller "sees" that changes as well. Simply said, the difference is whether the statement includes an assignment operator (`=`) or not.

With integers, you would always create a new integer object using an assignment (e.g. `x = 3`, or even `x += 3`). Also strings are immutable, so you cannot modify a string in a function, but only create a new string (e.g. `word = word.lower()`).

If you modify a list using one of its class methods, such as `list.append()`, you update the original object. But if you create and assign a new list, the original list will not be changed. So, to clear a list in a function, you could use `container.clear()` but not `container = []`. I hope the following example clarifies this:

```py
def add_numbers_to_container(container):
    for i in range(5):
        container.append(i)


def clear1(container):
    container = []
    # This creates a new list and assigns it to the local variable.
    # The original list is not modified!


def clear2(container):
    container.clear()
    # This clears the list that was passed as argument.


def main():
    new_list = []
    print(new_list)  # []
    add_numbers_to_container(new_list)
    print(new_list)  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    clear1(new_list)
    print(new_list)  # STILL [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] !
    clear2(new_list)
    print(new_list)  # []


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**ALSO NOTE:** if you have a number of functions/methods that are processing the same data, it's a good practice to create a class for it. This has both benefits: you don't have to pass the list to each function, but you don't have to create global variables as well. So you could easily handle multiple lists with the same code. See the following example code.

Method 4:

```py
class MyContainer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.container = []
        # Here the container is initialized with an empty list.

    def add_numbers(self, start, stop):
        for i in range(start, stop):
            self.container.append(i)

    def clear(self):
        # Both of the following lines are correct (only one is necessary):
        self.container = []
        self.container.clear()

    def print(self):
        print(self.container)


def main():
    # You could even create multiple independent containers, and use the
    # same functions for each object:
    container1 = MyContainer()
    container2 = MyContainer()

    container1.print()  # []
    container2.print()  # []

    container1.add_numbers(0, 5)
    container2.add_numbers(5, 8)

    container1.print()  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    container2.print()  # [5, 6, 7]

    container1.clear()
    container1.print()  # []


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: added pass, just for my purpose to keep track of where my function is ending!

Comment: so basically, sending the container as an argument to `func`(passing a reference to the container!) would simply let `func` manipulate it! and the func doesn't have to return this container!. I am little confused until `func` doesn't return a reference /container itself how the main program would be able to see the changes in the container? If this works, then in python we only return variables that are local to the `func` that were created and manipulated inside `func`, any data structure passed as an argument doesn't need to be returned, it implicitly gets returned!

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the object as a parameter (example 2) it should make a so-called by-reference passage so it doesn't copy the variable but just pass the pointer to that variable so it's basically the same as using a global variable, using the addictional return container (example 3) is redoundant for lists because they're passed as pointers. Instead for integers andother classes there is a big difference because the copy by value and copy by reference have differents effects. The first create a local copy and the changes won't affect the global variable while the second method would affect the global variable.

Comment: Good point about the integers (not for classes by the way!), but the question is specifically about data structures / containers. I don't agree with you that using globals is the same, because method #2 can be used on multiple objects, while method #1 only works on one hard-coded global variable.

Comment: For example, I'm reading a CSV file line by line and for each line, I am calling that `func()`, counting something and updating a dictionary with the count! which I passed as a reference, in a 2nd approach / used as a global variable in the 1st approach!.

Comment: @wovano, but when I pass a variable having Integer value as function arguments, it does get manipulated inside the `func` but never automatically get's returned to the main function as in case of a list/dictionary! Does that mean they are passed as a value? and I do need to return and catch them?

Comment: well I actually jumoed over the fact that passing by reference and using globals are different but I tought he asked what that means in python not at a logic level, by the way yes it is preferable to use function which are the most reusable. With classes I meant every kind of class (float is a class too) so I did not generalize because there are exception and honestly I'm not sure about how it behaves whit user-defined data structure

Comment: @anu, actually all types are classes in Python (even `int`s and `float`s, @Dario was right about that). The difference is between *modifying* the object or *creating* a new object. I've updated my answer to explain this in more detail. I hope it helps!